# Newton's methods, do we use Hessian matrix or its transpose?

Tags: derivatives, numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Im working with Newton method, and during I was trying to see why we got this expression, I fall into a problem, I find the same expression but instead of Hessian matrix I find his transpose. I can't figure where Im wrong D:

Here how I found that :

**Quick note of Newton's Method to aproximate zero of a function h:**
$$h: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n} $$
$$and$$
$$D_h : \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{L}(\mathbb{R}^n) $$

We must find the x such as:
$$D_h(x_n) (x-x_n)+h(x_n)=0$$
$$ x= x_n - D_h^{-1}(x_n)\ h(x_n)$$
$$So$$
$$x_{n+1}= x_n - D_h^{-1}(x_n)\ h(x_n)$$

**First I define my function f twice deferentiable:**
$$ f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$

We want to minimize this function so we want to find where the diferential is  zeros.
$$ D_f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{L(R^n)} $$

It's equivalent to find the zeros of the gradient :
$$ \nabla f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$

So our objectif is finding the zeros of the gradient vector.

$$Let \  \  g= \nabla f $$

To find the zeros of g we can use Newton's methods:
$$x_{n+1}= x_n - D_g^{-1}(x_n)\ g(x_n)$$
$$With$$
$$D_g : \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{M}_n $$
$$\hspace{30pt} x \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{dg_1(x)}{dx_1}  & \frac{dg_1(x)}{dx_2} & ... &\frac{dg_1(x)}{dx_n} \\
 ... & ... & &...\\ 
\frac{dg_n(x)}{dx_1}  &\frac{dg_n(x)}{dx_2} & ... &\frac{dg_n(x)}{dx_n}  \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\hspace{30pt}x \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{d{\nabla f}_1(x)}{dx_1}  & \frac{d{\nabla f}_1(x)}{dx_2} & ... &\frac{d{\nabla f}_1(x)}{dx_n} \\
 ... & ... & &...\\ 
\frac{d{\nabla f}_n(x)}{dx_1}  &\frac{d{\nabla f}_n(x)}{dx_2} & ... &\frac{d{\nabla f}_n(x)}{dx_n}  \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\hspace{30pt}x \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx_1 dx_1}  & \frac{d^2f(x)}{dx_2 dx_1} & ... &\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx_n dx_1} \\
 ... & ... & &...\\ 
\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx_1 dx_n}  &\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx_2 dx_n} & ... &\frac{d^2f(x)}{dx_n dx_n}  \end{bmatrix}=H^T(f(x))$$
$$Newton \ methods \ become:$$
$$x_{n+1}= x_n -H^T(f(x_n))^{-1}\  \nabla f(x_n)$$

But I find on the internet the Newton's method is :
$$ x_{n+1} = x_n -H(f(x_n))^{-1} \nabla f(x_n)$$

$$H(f) = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_n} \\ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2^2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2 \partial x_n} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_n \partial x_1} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_n \partial x_2} & \cdots & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_n^2} \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

So why I find the transpose of the hessian matrix instead of the hessian matrix ? D:

(I know that if the function is C² the hessian matrix is symetric but even if it's true and im right, why define hessian matrix like that and not directly define the hessian matrix like the transpose of the actual one )

Thanks for reading be nice with my english and my latex (that s my first time latex)

THANKS :)

Comment: The Hessian is always symmetric, thus $H^T=H$, so you got the wanted result.

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar Hessian matrix are not always symmetric ! Hessian matrix are symmetric if the seconds partials derivatives are continuous ( Schwarz's theorem)

Comment: Yes, but you are talking about a $C^2$ function, so the function is twice differentiable and the derivatives are continous aswell, in particular the partial derivatives are also countinous, so your function holds for Schwarz's Theorem. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) it is also stated that it needs to be twice-differentiable. So the Hessian **in your Question/Case** is always symmetric.

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar Tell me if im wrong but I said my function is twice differentiable not C2:
continious partial derivative => differentiable
differentiable =/> continious partial derivative

So in my example when I said it's twice differentiable, that dont mean that second partial derivative are continious

Comment: No you are totally right, it is well known, that there a differentiable functions, with non continuous derivatives. I assumed you meant it as $C^2$, since the Newton-Method requires $C^k$ like mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Generalizations). So I am confused why you would bother about differentiable functions, whose derivatives are not continuous?

Comment: in practice, unless you need super high precision, it is possible to smooth the function out and take the Newton method, in that sense, maybe taking an average of $sym(H(f))$ in the previous few iterations in the sequence can be a way, that mimics the effect.

Comment: @tychonovs-scholar Im not sure to understand why in higher dimension we need the function to be continious differentiable ( for R to R function différentiable is sufficient )but if it’s the case Thanks for your answer :-)

Comment: @Yimin You mean that I can always smooth my function to make it C2 to have  $$H^T = H$$ ?

Comment: as long your function is integrable, you can always convolve with mollifier.@Cauchy_Chlasse